# Matlab real time audio processing

Tags: matlab, audio-recording, audio-processing

I'm trying to record my microphone input and process it at the same time.

I tried with a loop with this inside:

```
recordblocking(recorder, 1);
y = getaudiodata(recorder);
% any processing on y
```

But while I'm doing something with **`y`**, I'm losing information since not recording continuously.

Is there something I could do to continuously record sound coming in my microphone, store it in some kind of buffer, and process chunks of it at the same time?

A delay isn't a problem, but I really need the recording and processing done simultaneously.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have Simulink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should use Stream processing like this:

```
% Visualization of audio spectrum frame by frame
Microphone = dsp.AudioRecorder;
Speaker = dsp.AudioPlayer;
SpecAnalyzer = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer;
tic;
while(toc<30)

audio = step(Microphone);
step(SpecAnalyzer,audio);
step(Speaker, audio);
end
```

you can find more information [here](http://es.mathworks.com/discovery/stream-processing.html) and also in this [presentation](http://in.mathworks.com/company/events/conferences/matlab-virtual-conference/2013/proceedings/design-and-prototype-real-time-dsp-systems-with-matlab.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the block processing framework in LTFAT
http://ltfat.github.io/doc/demos/demo_blockproc_basicloop_code.html

Edit: 
This is the main gist of the code:

```
   % Basic Control pannel (Java object)
   p = blockpanel({
                  {'GdB','Gain',-20,20,0,21},...
                  });

   % Setup blocktream
   fs = block('playrec','loadind',p);

   % Set buffer length to 30 ms
   L = floor(30e-3*fs);

   flag = 1;
   %Loop until end of the stream (flag) and until panel is opened
   while flag && p.flag
      gain = blockpanelget(p,'GdB');
      gain = 10^(gain/20);

      % Read the block
      [f,flag] = blockread(L);
      % Play the block and do the processing
      blockplay(f*gain);
   end
   blockdone(p);
```

Note that it is possible to specify input and output devices and their channels by passing additional arguments to the *block* function. List of available audio devices can be obtained by calling *blockdevices*.